# LED Bulb Color Temperatures

Tags: lighting, led

Why are 99% of the LED bulbs in stores either 2600K or 5000-5200K? I prefer 3000K - 4200K but have only found 1 option in all of my searching. Is there a technical reason, a marketing reason, or a legal reason for the limited options with LED light bulb color temperature?

Comment: I see most in 2700-2800K, or 4000K, or 5000K, with some 3000K scattered in there. ........... Where are you shopping?

Comment: Lowe's, Home Depot, WalMart, Amazon...Again, looking for 3000-4200.

Comment: I don't mean this to sound like I want shopping help; I'm more curious about why 2600 and 5000 K seem to be the vast majority of what's available.

Comment: 5000k is closer to daylight helps with "sad" in areas that dont have as much sunlight. 2600k is a good one for tomatoes they need the yellow/orange to produce fruit. Did a green house not long ago and that's what the master Gardner told me about the 2600k, Been using 5000+ to help with the "sad" here in Oregon.

Comment: In an unscientific survey of Home Depot's website, I saw 57 Warm White / Soft White bulbs (around 2700-2800K), 32 Bright White (3000K) and 13 Cool White (~4000K), and 25 Daylight bulbs (5000K). I didn't look at the color temperature of every bulb, just a few samples from each color  name, but it looks like though the  mid-range is underrepresented, there are still plenty of options. Bulbs.com had a similar distribution.

Comment: Interesting. When I search HD for A19 Cool White LED (no other filters), only 3 options show up. (Well, 4, but one was actually 2700K and not truly cool white.) And still, I have only seen 3000K or 4000K LED bulbs (A19 or BR30) in physical stores once. Which brings me back to the question of why. Are they just not popular? More difficult to make?

Comment: I recently bought 3000k 800 lumen (60w equivalent) bulbs at HD (Feit brand), $14 for a box of 6.

Comment: That was the one and only instance that I have seen. Got them for $9.97!